# Problem with WebServices using EJB. The error is: "..does not contain operation meta data.."

Tags: web-services, soap, ejb-3.0, ejb

I got an error as I mentioned above. My application has EJB WebServices, developing with MyEclipse and running on jboss4.2.2.GA. 
I use Eclipse's Web Services Explorer to invoke a WSDL operation. When I enter the parameters for the wsdl and click **Go** to invoke, I am getting this error in the SOAP Response Envelope;

```
<faultstring>Endpoint {http://local.ws.myService}LocalServicePort does not contain operation meta data for: {http://local.ws.myService}getPaymentStatus</faultstring>
```

If you have an idea about this problem I would be glad to hear that.
Thanks in advance.
Baris

**EDIT** : It was because of I set the wrong service binding endpoint. I added the right endpoint (for ex: http://192.110.10.10:8080/myServices-myServicesEJB/MyService?wsdl) and the error is gone. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of I set the wrong service binding endpoint.

I added the right endpoint (for ex: http://192.168.20.20:8080/myServices-myServicesEJB/MyService?wsdl) and the error is gone.

By the way, it is related to jboss configurations which is placed at;

```
[JBOSS_HOME]\server\node\deploy\jbossws.sar\jbossws.beans\META-INF\jboss-beans.xml
```

If you see like what i wrote below, it means the endpoint will be always set to that url: test.testApplication.com

```
<property name="webServiceHost">test.testApplication.com</property>
```

However, if you define the host such as:

```
<property name="webServiceHost">${jboss.bind.address}</property>
```

It means when you start jboss with this argument: -b192.168.20.20 (please replace with your ip address which jboss runs on) endpoints will be set to that address you bind, in this example it is 192.168.20.20